# Approach to find Average by X from a file.?

Tags: java, csv, hashmap, average

Let's say I have a CSV file.

For Example:

`City,Year,Income
Delhi,2001,12345
Mumbai,2001,43211
Hyderabad,2001,54322
Delhi,2002,76543
Mumbai,2002,43211
Hyderabad,2002,54322
Bangalore,2001,43211
Bangalore,2001,54322`

I want to find the average by City.

Output:

`Delhi - 876543
Mumbai - 86543
Hyderabad - 356785
Bangalore - 64352`

The approach which I used is by using multiple Map. But I guess it will be taking more space.

Can anyone suggest me a better approach to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your code whatever you tried so far so that people can give you Improvement suggestions?

Comment: @VarunJain the thing is there is no problem in my code it is working absolutely fine. The only thing is I wanted some different approach which I can try.

Comment: But how would someone know which approach you followed? So its always better to post your code and if it's not possible to post your code then try to post working chunks of it.

Answer (score 1):

First,we define a DTO to express the data in CSV file,one line one DTO

```
public class CityIncome {
        private String city;
        private String year;
        private int income;

        public CityIncome(String city, String year, int income) {
            this.city = city;
            this.year = year;
            this.income = income;
        }
    }
```

Second,read all data in CSV file into a `List<CityIncome>`

Third,use Java Stream API to group and reduce the result,may like this:

```
Map<String, Double> groupResult = cityIncomes.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(CityIncome::getCity, Collectors.averagingInt(CityIncome::getIncome)));
```

key of `groupResult` is city name,and value is the average income

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a couple of variables for each gender, 
`mCount`, `mTotal`, `fCount`, `fTotal`.

Read the csv line by line, incrementing `mCount` or `fCount` appropriately and adding the salary to `mTotal` or `fTotal`.

After you reach the end of the file,

just do `mTotal/mCount` and `fTotal/fCount` to get your averages.

Comment: But let's say we have a situation where we need to find the average on the basis of the cities for the past 10 years. Then? There can be N different cities.

Comment: Its a case by case thing, one solution can not be a catch all. If you write out all the details of the new case then I can suggest the best way I can think of.

Comment: I am looking for a generic solution that can be applied to any such problem of finding an average. Prob: find an average on the basis of the cities for the past 10 years.`City,Year,Income Delhi,2001,123456 Mumbai,2001,123456 Delhi,2002,4321 Hyderabad,2001,4321 Mumbai,2002,65432` and so on... Output I want is the result clubbed by cities.

Comment: I have edited the question. Your thoughts are welcome.